# Small number on Gmail's favicon

Tags: gmail

What does the small number mean next to the Gmail Inbox tab?  I am using Safari.  As you can see in the link below, the (1) following 'Inbox' refers to the number of unopened emails but I don't know what the small '6' is next to the Gmail mail icon.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What all "Google" products you are having an account in? say, Google Photos app, etc?

Comment: login to gmail, put "is:unread" in the search box and see if there are any old mails that are still unread?

Answer (score 1):

It means you "have" 6 unread messages in your inbox even if that is not true (sometimes).

This "future" is "broken". At the moment it shows past state eg. you had 6 emails in the past stage.

To explain my quotes for "future" and "broken": this unread-email-indicator works right, only if you never close your Gmail tab. This way it gets updated (with some delay) and it will show the right count of unread emails.

To resolve that **`6`** to show your actual state you will need to open and close your Gmail 2-3 times (with wait intervals between the opening and closing) until this indicator wakes up and gets updated